# I'm trying to avoid CodeIgniter routes regex overkill

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I'm looking for suggestions on how to avoid:

```
$route = array(
    'directory'             => 'accountdirectory/index',
    'directory/(:any)'          => 'accountdirectory/index/$1',
    'directory/(:any)/(:num)'       => 'accountdirectory/index/$1/$2' ...
```

by having a more forgiving single pattern if possible, where the route won't break if all segments aren't present:

`'directory(/)?(:any)?(/)?(:any)' => 'accountdirectory/index/$1/$2'`

To route

- directory/all
- directory/
- directory/all/10

Comment: can't you just route to accountdirectory/index and then use uri segments and ifs to redirect from there?

Comment: You're right. That seems to be the best practice for what I was trying to do. If you wan't to leave that as an answer, I'll certainly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can use one route:

```
$route = array(
    'directory' => 'accountdirectory/index',
    ...
)
```

And define the accountdirectory/index function like this:

```
public function index($arg1 = null, $arg2 = null) {
    if ($arg === 'all' && $arg2 !== null) {
        // directory/all/XXXX
    }
    elseif ($arg1 === 'all') {
        // directory/all
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

generally what I would do in situations like you describe is :

```
$route['404_override'] = 'directory';
```

then you can either use an if or switch statement in the constructor or index function to redirect from there based on the other uri segments.